# Typescript definition file - for a function, return actual property types, or custom property type itself?

Tags: typescript, conventions, typescript-definitions, apple-musickit-js

I'm trying to write a TypeScript type definitions file for an external JS library, [MusicKit JS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/musickitjs/musickit). I'm fairly new to TS (and especially declaring type definitions in TS). The MusicKit docs are, at times, not very descriptive, and I'd like to avoid inheriting this in the type definitions.

As a result, I'm unsure of what return type to use on a function definition.

For example, take the `authorize` function. In the MusicKit docs, it is defined as such: [Link to relevant docs section](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/musickitjs/musickit/musickitinstance/2992701-authorize)

```
Promise authorize();
```

where the return type is a `Promise` (containing a `musicUserToken`, although not specified).

---

In my type definitions, I define it as so:

```
authorize(): Promise<MusicKitInstance.musicUserToken>;
```

where the `musicUserToken` is defined

```
musicUserToken: string | undefined;
```

and the `MusicKitInstance` is a property of the `MusicKit` object.

To get this to work, I had to declare another module:

```
declare module MusicKitInstance {
    export type musicUserToken = string | undefined;
    ...
}
```

as I want to be clear on what is returned, a `musicUserToken`. But should I just ditch the type definition and return `string | undefined` directly? If I used the appropriate custom types for all the functions in the library, I would have to manually define all the types listed under the `MusicKitInstance` in the `MusicKitInstance` module, and then use them in the `MusicKit` module definitions. I'm not sure if this is a good practice.

Comment: I don't see how we can answer this with anything but opinions.  I don't think there's an "official" convention for this anywhere; TypeScript itself doesn't dictate such things.  I can tell you "either way is fine (although if you're defining custom types and care about conventions please use `MusicUserToken` and not `musicUserToken`)", but that's just my opinion and not really appropriate for a Stack Overflow answer.  How can this question be answered authoritatively?

Comment: @jcalz I'm not sure on an authoritative answer, I agree it is subjective. However, I just wanted to avoid a "definitely don't do this" type of situation; I wasn't sure if defining types in this way, for an external library, was something to be avoided. Thanks for your input. :)